# How to get variable from ng-container and compare with another variable

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I use the table, and I also have an expandable table, my goal is to display only those rows in the expanded table that refer to the first table. It should show by first the same ID without a second line(underlined with a red line)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZluAe.jpg)

Here is my code:

```js
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {NotifierService} from 'angular-notifier';
import {MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';
import {IncomeContract} from '../model/incomeContract';
import {Status} from '../model/status';
import {SubjectOfContract} from '../model/subjectOfContract';
import {IncomeContractService} from '../service/income-contract.service';
import {StatusService} from '../service/status.service';
import {SubjectOfContractService} from '../service/subjectOfContract.service';
import {HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';
import {IncomeAdditional} from '../model/incomeAdditional';
import {IncomeAdditionalService} from '../service/income-additional.service';
import {animate, state, style, transition, trigger} from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-income-contract-list',
  templateUrl: './income-contract-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./income-contract-list.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('detailExpand', [
      state('collapsed', style({height: '0px', minHeight: '0', display: 'none'})),
      state('expanded', style({height: '*'})),
      transition('expanded <=> collapsed', animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)')),
    ]),
  ],
})
export class IncomeContractListComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'number', 'date', 'client',  'subjectOfContract', 'amountOfContract','paymentProcedure',
    'termOfService', 'prepaymentDate', 'executionDate', 'currentAmount', 'controlAmount', 'delay', 'penalty', 'status', 'action'];
  displayedColumnsAdditional: string[] = ['numberOfIncome', 'number', 'date', 'client',  'subjectOfContract', 'amountOfContract','paymentProcedure',
    'termOfService', 'prepaymentDate', 'executionDate', 'currentAmount', 'controlAmount', 'delay', 'penalty', 'status', 'action'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<IncomeContract[]>;
  dataSourceAdditional: MatTableDataSource<IncomeAdditional[]>;
  expandedElement: IncomeContract;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  // @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  incomeList: IncomeContract[] = [];
  incomeAdditionalList: IncomeAdditional[] = [];
  exportCols = [];
  isCollapsed: boolean = true;
  isCollapsedAdd: boolean = true;
  filter = {
    number: '',
    dateStart: null,
    dateEnd: null,
    client: '',
    status: null,
    subjectOfContract: null
  };
  save_id = {
    contract_number: null
  };
  filterForAdditional = {
    number: '',
    dateStart: null,
    dateEnd: null,
    client: '',
    status: null,
    subjectOfContract: null
  };
  statusList: Status[] = [];
  subjectList: SubjectOfContract[] = [];

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private incomeService: IncomeContractService,
    private incomeAdditionalService: IncomeAdditionalService,
    private notifierService: NotifierService,
    private statusService: StatusService,
    private subjectService: SubjectOfContractService) {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<IncomeContract[]>([]);
    this.dataSourceAdditional = new MatTableDataSource<IncomeAdditional[]>([]);
  }

  toggleCollapse() {
    this.isCollapsed = !this.isCollapsed;
  }

  toggleCollapseAdd() {
    this.isCollapsedAdd = !this.isCollapsedAdd;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.updateStatusList();
    this.updateSubjectOfContractList();
    // this.restoreCols();
    this.loadData();
    this.loadAdditionalData();
  }

  editIncome(incomeContract: IncomeContract) {
    if (incomeContract != null)
      this.router.navigate(['income/' + incomeContract.id]);
    else
      this.router.navigate(['income']);
  }

  editAdditional(incomeAdditional: IncomeAdditional) {
    if (incomeAdditional != null)
      this.router.navigate(['income-additional/' + incomeAdditional.id]);
    else
      this.router.navigate(['income-additional']);
  }

  addAdditional() {
    this.router.navigate(['income-additional']);
  }

  addIncome() {
    this.router.navigate(['income']);
  }

  removeIncome(incomeContract: IncomeContract) {
    if (confirm('Вы действительно хотите удалить запись?')) {
      this.incomeService.remove(incomeContract.id).subscribe(() => {
        this.loadData();
        this.loadAdditionalData();
        this.notifierService.notify('success', 'Данные успешно удалены');
      });
    }
  }

  removeAdditional(incomeAdditional: IncomeAdditional) {
    if (confirm('Вы действительно хотите удалить запись?')) {
      this.incomeAdditionalService.remove(incomeAdditional.id).subscribe(() => {
        this.loadData();
        this.loadAdditionalData();
        this.notifierService.notify('success', 'Данные успешно удалены');
      });
    }
  }

  loadData() {
    let params = new HttpParams()
      .append('number', this.filter.number)
      .append('client', this.filter.client)
      .append('statusId', this.filter.status == null ? 0 : this.filter.status.id)
      .append('subjectOfContractId', this.filter.subjectOfContract == null ? 0 : this.filter.subjectOfContract.id)

    if (this.filter.dateStart != null)
      params = params.append('dateStart',this.filter.dateStart.getTime());
    if (this.filterForAdditional.dateEnd != null)
      params = params.append('dateEnd',this.filterForAdditional.dateEnd.getTime());

    this.incomeService.getAll({params: params}).subscribe(data => {
      this.incomeList = data;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<IncomeContract[]>(data);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      // this.sort.active = 'id';
      // this.sort.direction = 'desc';
      // this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    });
  }

  loadAdditionalData(){
    let params = new HttpParams()
      .append('number', this.filterForAdditional.number)
      .append('client', this.filterForAdditional.client)
      .append('statusId', this.filterForAdditional.status == null ? 0 : this.filterForAdditional.status.id)
      .append('subjectOfContractId', this.filterForAdditional.subjectOfContract == null ? 0 : this.filterForAdditional.subjectOfContract.id)

    if (this.filterForAdditional.dateStart != null)
      params = params.append('dateStart',this.filterForAdditional.dateStart.getTime());
    if (this.filterForAdditional.dateEnd != null)
      params = params.append('dateEnd',this.filterForAdditional.dateEnd.getTime());

    this.incomeAdditionalService.getAll({params: params}).subscribe(data => {
      this.incomeAdditionalList = data;
      this.dataSourceAdditional = new MatTableDataSource<IncomeAdditional[]>(data);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      // this.sort.active = 'id';
      // this.sort.direction = 'desc';
      // this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    });
  }

  // public restoreCols(): void {
  //   this.colRemoved = false;
  //   this.exportCols = [
  //     {utility: 'id', caption: 'ID'},
  //     {utility: 'journal', caption: '№ по журналу'},
  //     {utility: 'startDate', caption: 'Дата начала события'},
  //     {utility: 'endDate', caption: 'Дата завершения события'},
  //     // {utility: 'created', caption: 'Дата создания'},
  //     {utility: 'system', caption: 'Система'},
  //     {utility: 'device', caption: 'Устройство'},
  //     {utility: 'eventTypes', caption: 'События'},
  //     {utility: 'region', caption: 'Узел сети (регион)'},
  //     // {utility: '', caption: 'Длительность' },
  //     {utility: 'problemTickets', caption: '№ ПБ'},
  //     {utility: 'operator', caption: 'Оповещения'},
  //     {utility: 'note', caption: 'Описание'},
  //     {utility: 'description', caption: 'Причина'},
  //     {utility: 'attendant', caption: 'Дежурный'}
  //     // {utility: 'category', caption: 'Категория'}
  //   ];
  //
  // }

  // downloadCSV() {
  //   this.eventService.exportCSV(this.exportCols).subscribe(data => {
  //     let blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'});
  //     let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  //     let filename = 'events.csv';
  //     if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
  //       navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
  //     } else {
  //       let a = document.createElement('a');
  //       a.href = url;
  //       a.download = filename;
  //       document.body.appendChild(a);
  //       a.click();
  //       document.body.removeChild(a);
  //     }
  //     window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  //   });
  // }

  // downloadExcel() {
  //   this.eventService.exportExcel(this.exportCols).subscribe(data => {
  //     let blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'});
  //     let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  //     let filename = 'events.xls';
  //     if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
  //       navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
  //     } else {
  //       let a = document.createElement('a');
  //       a.href = url;
  //       a.download = filename;
  //       document.body.appendChild(a);
  //       a.click();
  //       document.body.removeChild(a);
  //     }
  //     window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  //   });
  // }


//  ----------------------------------------------------------FILTER----------------------------------------------------

  private updateStatusList() {
    this.statusService.getAll().subscribe(response => {
      this.statusList = response;
      let emptyStatus = new Status();
      emptyStatus.id = 0;
      emptyStatus.name = 'Все';
      this.statusList.unshift(emptyStatus);
      this.filter.status = this.statusList[0];
    });
  }

  private updateSubjectOfContractList() {
    this.subjectService.getAll().subscribe(response => {
      this.subjectList = response;
      let emptySubject = new SubjectOfContract();
      emptySubject.id = 0;
      emptySubject.shortName = 'Все';
      this.subjectList.unshift(emptySubject);
      this.filter.subjectOfContract = this.subjectList[0];
    });
  }

  resetFilter() {
    this.filter.number = '';
    this.filter.client = '';
    this.filter.dateStart = null;
    this.filter.dateEnd = null;
    this.filter.status = this.statusList[0];
    this.filter.subjectOfContract = this.subjectList[0];
    this.loadData();
    this.loadAdditionalData();
  }

  resetFilterAdd() {
    this.filterForAdditional.number = '';
    this.filterForAdditional.client = '';
    this.filterForAdditional.dateStart = null;
    this.filterForAdditional.dateEnd = null;
    this.filterForAdditional.status = this.statusList[0];
    this.filterForAdditional.subjectOfContract = this.subjectList[0];
    this.loadData();
    this.loadAdditionalData();
  }
}

// export class SomeComponent {
//   number_contract = '';
//
//   save() {
//     console.log(this.number_contract);
//   }
// }
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

.example-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 500px;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.mat-table {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 500px;
}

.element-row {
  position: relative;
}

.element-row:not(.expanded) {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.element-row:not(.expanded):hover {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.element-row.expanded {
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

table {
  border: black solid 1px;
  background-color: white;
}
mat-paginator {
  background-color: white;
}

button {
  padding: 5px;
}

#filterButton {
  margin-top: 10%;
}

table th, table td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: .1em solid rgba(0, 40, 80, 0.51);
}

.h2-header {
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 0 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.space-input {
  margin-left: 8%;
}

/*###########################################################*/

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 76px 0 0;
  box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(168, 203, 243, 0.1);
}

.sidebar-sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.sidebar-sticky {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  height: calc(100vh - 48px);
  padding-top: .5rem;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.feather {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

.sidebar .nav-link .feather {
  margin-right: 4px;
  color: #999;
}

.sidebar .nav-link:hover .feather, .sidebar .nav-link.active .feather {
  color: inherit;
}

.sidebar .nav-link {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #2a292a;
}

.nav-link {
  display: block;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
}

a {
  color: #007bff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.white-icon {
  color: black;
}

button:focus, button:active:focus, button.active:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  outline-style: none !important;
}

.mat-elevation-z8{
  background-color: bisque;
  border: black solid 1px;

}

.mat-header-cell{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

.btn-menu {
  background-color: #94cdee;
  font-size: medium;
  border: black solid .1em;
  min-height: 40px;
  max-height: 40px;
  min-width: 132px;
  max-width: 132px;
  margin: 8px 16px 8px 16px;
  align-items: center;
}

.btn:hover {
  text-decoration: none
}

.btn.focus, .btn:focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 .2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, .25)
}

.btn.disabled, .btn:disabled {
  opacity: .65
}

.btn:not(:disabled):not(.disabled) {
  cursor: pointer
}

a.btn.disabled, fieldset:disabled a.btn {
  pointer-events: none
}

.open-event {
  background-color: pink;
}

.filter {
  background-color: white;
  height: 150%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.mat-cell {
  text-align: center ;
}

.mat-table {
  font-family: Verdana ;
}
```

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort multiTemplateDataRows class="mat-elevation-z8" style="width: 100%">
      <details>
        <summary>
         <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" >{{row.id}}</td>
         </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="number">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> № договора</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.number}} </td>

          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Дата договора</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.date | date:'dd.MM.yyyy H:mm'}}
            </td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="client">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Заказчик</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.client}}</td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="subjectOfContract">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Предмет договора</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.subjectOfContract?.fullName}}</td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="amountOfContract">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Сумма договора</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.amountOfContract}}</td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="paymentProcedure">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Порядок расчётов</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.paymentProcedure}}</td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="termOfService">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Срок оказания услуг</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.termOfService}}</td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="prepaymentDate">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Дата аванса</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.prepaymentDate | date:'dd.MM.yyyy H:mm'}}
            </td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="executionDate">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Срок исполнения договора</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.executionDate | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy H:mm'}}
            </td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="currentAmount">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Текущая сумма</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.currentAmount}}</td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="controlAmount">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Контрольная сумма</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.controlAmount}}</td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="delay">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Количество просроченных дней по оплате</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.delay}}</td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="penalty">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Сумма пени</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.penalty}}</td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Статус</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.status?.name}}</td>
          </ng-container>
        </summary>
        скрытое/показанное содержимое
      </details>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <!--TODO rework with material-icons-->
          <button mat-icon-button (click)="addAdditional()">
            <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
          </button>
          <br/>
          <button mat-icon-button (click)="editIncome(row)">
            <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
          </button>
          <button mat-icon-button (click)="removeIncome(row)">
            <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

    <!-- Expanded Content Column - The detail row is made up of this one column that spans across all columns -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length">
        <div class="example-element-detail"
             [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
          <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceAdditional" style="width: 100%" matSort>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="numberOfIncome">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>№ основного договора</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.incomeContract?.number}}</td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="number">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> № договора</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.number}}</td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Дата договора</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.date | date:'dd.MM.yyyy H:mm'}}
              </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="client">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Заказчик</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.client}}</td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="subjectOfContract">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Предмет договора</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.subjectOfContract?.fullName}}</td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="amountOfContract">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Сумма договора</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.amountOfContract}}</td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="paymentProcedure">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Порядок расчётов</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.paymentProcedure}}</td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="termOfService">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Срок оказания услуг</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.termOfService}}</td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="prepaymentDate">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Дата аванса</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.prepaymentDate | date:'dd.MM.yyyy H:mm'}}
              </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="executionDate">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Срок исполнения договора</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.executionDate | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy H:mm'}}
              </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="currentAmount">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Текущая сумма</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.currentAmount}}</td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="controlAmount">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Контрольная сумма</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.controlAmount}}</td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="delay">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Количество просроченных дней по оплате</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.delay}}</td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="penalty">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Сумма пени</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.penalty}}</td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Статус</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.status?.name}}</td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                <!--TODO rework with material-icons-->
                <button mat-icon-button (click)="editAdditional(row)">
                  <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                </button>
                <button mat-icon-button (click)="removeAdditional(row)">
                  <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                </button>
              </td>
            </ng-container>
<!--            </ng-container>-->
            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsAdditional"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsAdditional;">
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: displayedColumns;"
        class="example-element-row"
        [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"
        (click)="expandedElement = element">
    </tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="example-detail-row"></tr>
  </table>
```

I want compare row.number from line 11 with row.incomeContract?.number from line 110, if they are equals then I'll show it in expanded table